# White graph in a scatter plot in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot

When I run:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(1,0)
```

I obtain a white graph instead of a point.

Answer (score 0):

plt.scatter(x,y) , takes argument as array or singular value if provide comma seperated values.
Ideally you should pass two array to it having x-coordinate and y-coordinate.

```
x = [1,2,3,]
y = [2,3,4]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

this will plot (1,2) ,(2,3),(3,4) on the graph.